# TextArea cursor position

Tags: dart, dart-html

I would like control the cursor in a textarea.

I tried with JavaScript method, but nothing is working.

```dart
void main()
{
    tchat           my_tchat = null;
    TextAreaElement input;

    input = querySelector('#input');
    input.onKeyPress.listen((key) {
        if (key.keyCode == 13)
        {
            if (my_tchat == null) {
                my_tchat = new tchat('ws://127.0.0.1:4040/ws', input.value);
                input.attributes['placeholder'] = "Put msg here...";
            }
            else
                my_tchat.send(input.value);
            input.value = "";
        }
    });
}
```

input.setSelectionRange() is not working.

Comment: Your code is not showing how you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it this way and it works for me

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  var rnd = new Random();
  var my_tchat;
  TextAreaElement input = document.querySelector('#input');

  input.onKeyPress.listen((key) {
    print(key);
  });

  new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
    var l = input.value.length;
    if (l > 0) {
      var pos = rnd.nextInt(l);
      input.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Just for demonstration setting the selection range every 10 seconds while typing.

Comment: It's not working, the cursor stay at the same place.

Comment: I have modified the example in my answer. The cursor jumps around every second.

Comment: It's not not working.. I use this : <textarea id="input" placeholder="Entrez un pseudo..." rows="2" style="resize: vertical; width: 80vw;"></textarea>

Comment: I updated my example to recognize zero text length (I had some chars as value in HTML). I used your HTML snippet and it worked.

Comment: The cursor stay on the rows 2.

Comment: What Dart version are you using? `dart --version` on the command line.

Comment: Dart VM version: 1.2.0 (Tue Feb 25 07:31:27 2014) on "macos_x64"

Comment: Maybe there was a bug. I use 1.3.0-dev.7.10. You can either download Dart from the dev channel or wait a few days to get 1.3. I expect a stabel 1.3 to be released very soon (not sure though).